# Mongo adapter session store sailsjs

Tags: sails.js

In config/sessions.js , i have commented the following lines:

```
// Uncomment the following lines to use your Mongo adapter as a session store
//     adapter: 'mongo',
//     host: 'localhost',
//     port: 27017, 
//     db: 'sourceguru',
//        auto_reconnect: false,
//     collection: 'session'
```

as i dont want to use collection : 'session'.

But when i do sails lift , i am getting an error as below.

error: No session data returned, and an error was encountered saving session data for the first time: undefined.

How this can be resolved?

Comment: They are all commented out by default and thus using memory as session, and there should not be error when you do sail lift.

Comment: ya i uncommented and used sessions and then when i comment again , i got this error from sails.io.js (within assets/js) in console.

Comment: should only be `module.exports.session = { secret: 'abc' };` that it.